# MasterPage link is changed in sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

So I have a link in my header placeholder in my MasterPage that takes me to my gallery

```
<a href="Gallery.aspx" class="logo-text">
```

Link is:

```
http://localhost:50803/Gallery.aspx
```

I created a subfolder called "Order" and used the MasterPage in one of the pages

Then I tried clicking the link in my header and it took me to

```
http://localhost:50803/Order/Gallery.aspx
```

Is there any way to change it so it takes me to the intended link?

Comment: `href="/Gallery.aspx"`

Comment: Holy, that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: If you do not add a `/` (root) or `../` (parent folder) IIS will look in the same folder, in your case Order.